# kSOAP2 output / org.xmlpull.v1.xmlpullparserexception expected start_tag

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I have a standard code to call a `.net webservice`

I get `exception "org.xmlpull.v1.xmlpullparserexception expected start_tag"` at line

```
transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION,soapSerializationEnvelope);
```

However, if i call the same webservice from a `.NET code` i get a well structured proper output as desired.

It primarily seems that from `kSOAP2`, there is a definite output that it gets but when it goes to parse further w.r.t SoapPrimitive objects, it fails.

So, is there other way to look at the actual output (actual soap envelope) received and then may be parse it myself appropriately.

Comment: is your .NET webservice returning a primitive type? If not then you should try using the SoapObject in place of the SoapPrimitive type.

Comment: Its returning a string, so yes...SoapObject should be here, but thats not where i am facing problem. It is getting stuck at transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION,soapSerializationEnvelope);
So, how do i see actual/raw soapenvelope...for verification purpose, since in the call method that parsing exception occurs

Comment: I see that envelope goes perfectly as desired by a call to "transportSE.requestDump" and get a empty string by a call to "transportSE.responseDump" and i get a null o/p for a call to "soapSerializationEnvelope.bodyIn"...Any inputs guys...am really stuck...i mean i can't see anything different to do, primarily other non-mobile clients are able to fetch desired response from the same given web-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well now that I've solved my original problem hit this one!

I found that ksoap2 couldn't parse the response... specifically org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(type, namespace, name) threw the following exception.

```
WARN/System.err(2330): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <h1>@1:4 in java.io.InputStreamReader@47ff3050)
```

Note that h1 tag. That comes from `<h1>404 Not Found</h1>` ... so yes, be aware your response may be from a website but not your web service :)

Hope that helps someone one day

Answer (score 2):

I'm investigating a similar problem I'm having. Stumbled across this comment

> When I use SoapEnvelope.VER11, it works fine, But when I use 
>   SoapEnvelope.VER12, it gives me error: 
>   "org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG".

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b585862b6e939fd2

Perhaps we are having compatibility issues regarding the soap version. Also connecting to a dot net service you may need to set `envelope.dotNet = true;` .. but you've probably done that

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this START_TAG Exception but in my case it was because my values for

```
METHOD_NAME="";
NAMESPACE ="";      
SOAP_ACTION ="";
URL ="";
```

were not correct.

Now How to find out the correct values of these parameters you can [Check out my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16956397/1206052)

```
SoapObject req = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
            //SoapObject req = new SoapObject(Namespace_Server,MethodName_Server);

    //req.addProperty("ImageData", Base64.encode(data));
    req.addProperty("ImageData", data);
    req.addProperty("login", CommonStaticData.getusername());
    req.addProperty("password",CommonStaticData.getpassword());
    req.addProperty("recipeId",FileID);

    MarshalBase64 mbase = new MarshalBase64();// marshal is used to serialize the byte array

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelop.bodyOut = req;
    envelop.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC2001;
    envelop.dotNet = true;
    envelop.setOutputSoapObject(req);


    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    mbase.register(envelop);


    aht.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelop);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same error, my exception was this "position:START_TAG @2:7"

but I've fixed because I was naming in a wrong way a parameter, the name must be exactly as is specified on the XSD.

```
     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
     request.addProperty("arg0_java_lang_String", "Club");
```

in the **addPropery** method I was using a wrong parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

After making sure the url of webservice is **reachable** by using the below code by watching variable **`urlc.getResponseCode()`** for response code while altering the ip from **localhost ,fixed ,external and finally to 10.0.2.2**

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts/4009133#comment24565402_4009133
        /* ConnectivityManager cm =
                    (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {//netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
                    return true;
                }
                return false;*/

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474089/how-to-check-currently-internet-connection-is-available-or-not-in-android?rq=1             
                boolean connected = false;
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)_context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || 
                            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        //we are connected to a network
                        connected=true;
                        return connected;
                    }
                    else
                        {
                        connected=false;
                        return false;
                        }
    }

    public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection() {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            try {
                //String url = "http://www.google.com",
                String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8089/UNIV_AXIS_DYN_WEB/services/ServiceMethods?wsdl",
                        proxy = "proxy.rss.jo",
                        port= "8080";
                URL server = new URL(url);
                Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
                /*systemProperties.setProperty("http.prosyHost",proxy);
                systemProperties.setProperty("http.prosyHost",port);*/
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (server.openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(500); 
                urlc.connect();
                System.out.println(urlc.getResponseCode());
                return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No network available!");
            return false;
        }

    }
```

For me i got this hint  "not the missing character **s** in the below"

**`[ERROR] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method login
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: namespace mismatch require http://services.univ.rss found http://service.univ.rss`**

The rest of log tomcat etc

```
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:190)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And yes after tracing the LogCat i did not check th tomcat server log eve if the service was tested by [SoapUi](http://www.soapui.org/) successfully , you should monitor all logs in every change test , i even forgot at first to start the database service so be carefull :)

**The Soap Call**

```
public SoapObject SoapCall(Vector<PropertyInfo> propertyInfo)

    {       

         Integer parametersSize = propertyInfo.size();

         //Initialize soap request + add parameters
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

         for(int i=0;i<parametersSize;i++)
         {
             request.addProperty(propertyInfo.get(i));
         }


        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        //envelope.dotNet = false; if service of type asmx .NET
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        Log.d("App Log c ","c");

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            System.out.println(androidHttpTransport.getPort());
            // Make the soap call.
            //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
             androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                      

             SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
             //Log.i("App Log 1 ", response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.       
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
        Log.i("App Log 2 ", result.toString());
        Log.i("App Log 2 ", result.getProperty(0).toString());

        return result;

    }
```

```
 Vector<PropertyInfo> vectorProperyInfo = new Vector<PropertyInfo>();

            PropertyInfo userProp = new PropertyInfo();
            userProp.setName("userName");
            userProp.setValue(username);
            userProp.setType(String.class);
            vectorProperyInfo.addElement(userProp);

            PropertyInfo passProp = new PropertyInfo();
            passProp.setName("pass");
            passProp.setValue(password);
            passProp.setType(String.class);
            vectorProperyInfo.addElement(passProp);

            SoapObject result = soapUtil.SoapCall(vectorProperyInfo);

           if (result != null && result.getProperty(0).toString().equals("1")) {
            return "LOGIN_SUCCESS";// for a student
        }
```

**P.S** My Db Is Oracle and webservice is soap and used  [axis2-1.2 bin](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/axis2/1_2/axis2-1.2.zip) And tested on Android 4.0 the above error response code was 500 [Internal Error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html)