# Android getActiveNetworkInfo() - Do it checks only for network connection or internet connection too?

Tags: android

A lot of topics about how to check internet connecton use getActiveNetworkInfo() but the documentation and my experience tell me that it only check network connection. Am I correct?

So to test internet connection what are the best method? requestRouteToHost() being the host a internet host?

Comment: it does check internet connection too.

Comment: Are you sure? Because if I disconnect my router from the internet the device still says that there is internet :s

Comment: mm, read this question, answer from binnyb seems correct.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474089/how-to-check-currently-internet-connection-is-available-or-not-in-android

Comment: I'm using the same code and if I remove the adsl cable from the router it still say the device is connect and only when I turn off the router it says there are no network connected.

Answer (score 0):

getActiveNetworkInfo() only refers to direct networks connection (Ethernet, wifi,...) for check if you have internet I usually try to reach www.google.com for example or other web or my own server.