# How to check if I have enabled WIFI before downloading a file?

Tags: java, android, android-internet

I have a Button that downoad a File, and works fine. If I dont have Internet conection, the file doesnt download (obviously). The problem is that the app continues trying to download, instead of stop it.

I want to show a Toast saying "The device its not connected" or some stuff like that and NOT begin the download process then. I want a function that returns true or false if I have WIFI connection avaiable AT THE MOMENT or not

I try with the answers of these post: [How to check currently internet connection is available or not in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474089/how-to-check-currently-internet-connection-is-available-or-not-in-android) , but the function retuns always true, even with Airplane mode.

I download the File with a DownloadManager and continues after download with a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: `I try with the answers of these post` which one did you try?

Comment: https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch

Comment: OK I am thinking that the problem is how I test the code. I was testing it with the emulator, removing my laptop's wifi conections. But thats not the point. I have to remove the wifi conection manually on the emulator. Now it worked. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add this permission in Manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Following condition will help you

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo wifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (wifi.isConnected()){
    // If Wi-Fi connected
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() /*Context field*/,"Please Connect to Wifi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: OK, it worked  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Add this permission in Manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Use this condition to check if Wifi Connected or not**

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager);getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
// Do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's Network connectivity checking code

```
public class NetworUtil {
  private static NetworkInfo activeNetwork;
  public static boolean isInternetConnected(Context context) {
      if (context == null)
         return false;
      else {
          ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
          return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
 }
}
```

Below permission must be required in the AndroidManifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```