# How to identify NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME, URL and SOAP_ACTION from WSDL and SOAP message

Tags: wsdl, soap-client, ws-security, wsse

I have some problem in parsing a SOAP web service. How can i identify the NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME, URL and SOAP_ACTION from WSDL and also how can i handle  using SoapObject.

I want to call the soap in android.

**Below are the WSDL AND SOAP REQUEST XML.**

WSDL:

https://e1jas01.domain.cssus.com:8091/DV910/RI_AddressBookManager?WSDL

Thanks,
Gowtham.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, downloading SoapUI will help you a lot, when you create a new project there and import that URL, you will see namespaces and method names properly. For the Soap action; for each operation there is 1 soap action. From that link first you should find the operation which you want to use then you will see soap action of that operation.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/

Here, there is a tutorial about creating soap objects etc.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response. using SoapUI i found all the params . Also how can i use the security header element to the soaoObject. Is there any way to include that.

Comment: http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20122/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSOAPSEC_manual
Here is the logic, but include part depends the language you use

Answer (score 0):

It might help others who are finding it difficult that's why i am posting,
this stackoverflow question explains the process of identifying NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME, URL and SOAP_ACTION 
[ksoap2 org.xmlpull.v1.xmlpullparserexception expected start_tag error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430136/ksoap2-org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparserexception-expected-start-tag-error)