# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, android-asynctask, ksoap2

Hello I new in webservice here i am using SOAP service and run on localhost but getting this error             Here is my code:                                                                                 public class Neteesh extends Activity{

```
private static final String URL = "http://localhost:7642/Service1.asmx";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

TextView textView = new TextView(this);

setContentView(textView);


new LongOperation().execute("");
}


private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... HelloWorldResult) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String value = new String();
        System.out.println("Inside getLognoperation method...........");
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("billId", HelloWorldResult);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet=true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        try
        {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive  resultString = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            value = resultString.toString();
            System.out.println("This getAccountsNames xmls is : "+value);
        }   catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        return value;
    }           
}   
}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
  11-16 11:11:48.371: W/System.err(1324): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <HTML>@2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4101fc30) 
11-16 11:11:48.371: W/System.err(1324):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2046)
11-16 11:11:48.371: W/System.err(1324):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127)
11-16 11:11:48.381: W/System.err(1324):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
11-16 11:11:48.381: W/System.err(1324):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
11-16 11:11:48.381: W/System.err(1324):     at com.example.helloworldwebservice.Neteesh$LongOperation.doInBackground(Neteesh.java:55)
11-16 11:11:48.381: W/System.err(1324):     at com.example.helloworldwebservice.Neteesh$LongOperation.doInBackground(Neteesh.java:1)
11-16 11:11:48.381: W/System.err(1324):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-16 11:11:48.381: W/System.err(1324):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-16 11:11:48.391: W/System.err(1324):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-16 11:11:48.391: W/System.err(1324):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-16 11:11:48.404: W/System.err(1324):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-16 11:11:48.404: W/System.err(1324):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-16 11:11:48.404: W/System.err(1324): [ 11-16 11:11:48.404  1324: 1337 I/expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG Exception
```

Please edit question if my structure is wrong, How to solve it.I need string response which one in webservice. please help thanks in Advance..

Comment: Are you sure to pass a String Array in soap request object at this line `request.addProperty("billId", HelloWorldResult);` ??

Comment: @Mukesh Kumar   Sory but this is final code Is that any require line than suggest me here...

Comment: I am not very much sure but for testing just set a String not a String array i.e. `request.addProperty("billId", "TextForId");` or `request.addProperty("billId", HelloWorldResult[0]);` and then run it.

Comment: @Mukeshkumar  I change HelloWorldResult   to HelloWorldResult[0] than error was changed new error is:                                                                      11-15 14:12:51.714: W/System.err(1662): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 7642): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
11-15 14:12:51.760: W/System.err(1662):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)

Comment: Is this emulator error???

Comment: thanks but there are anther error: 11-15 14:32:54.754: W/System.err(1712): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <HTML>@2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4101fc88) How to solve it?? thanks in advance..

Comment: Any one have solution of this problem?

Comment: Hello everyone.. Please give me right solution!!!!  thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android emulator run on Virtual Machine therefore you have to use this

```
private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:7642/Service1.asmx";
```

instead of

```
private static final String URL = "http://localhost:7642/Service1.asmx";
```

And then

```
protected String doInBackground(String... HelloWorldResult) 
    {
      .....
      SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
      request.addProperty("billId", HelloWorldResult[0]);
      .....
  }
```

As you are trying now...

Comment: thanks but there are anther error:   11-15 14:32:54.754: W/System.err(1712): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <HTML>@2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4101fc88) 
How to solve it??   thanks in advance..

Comment: @parthpatibandha see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430136/ksoap2-org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparserexception-expected-start-tag-error

Comment: this error occured becouse my service on localhost? or some another problem?

Comment: @parthpatibandha As discussed in this stackoverflow.com/questions/12430136/… answer, There may me no of reason of this error... take a look of google search https://www.google.co.in/search?q=org.xmlpull.v1.xmlpullparserexception+expected+start_tag&rlz=1C1CHMO_enIN508IN508&oq=org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException%3A&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3268j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8