# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException:expected start tag

Tags: android

I have a c# webservice and an android project.I am getting an error, that is

`'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException:expected:START_TAG{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope(position:START_TAG<HTML>@2.7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@b3da9588)'  xmlpullparseexception`

error.

I couldn't solve this problem.

## Here is Android Code Part

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/findUye";

    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "findUye";

    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:51249/WebSite1/Service1.asmx";

    TextView tvData1;
    EditText edata;
    Button button;
    String studentNo;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yeni_main);
          tvData1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


            button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
                    propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                    propertyInfo.name = "eid";

                    edata =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    studentNo=edata.getText().toString();

                    request.addProperty(propertyInfo, studentNo);

                            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                            envelope.dotNet = true;

                            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

                            try  {                    
                            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                    
                            Object response = envelope.getResponse();                    
                            tvData1.setText(response.toString());                    
                            }  catch (Exception exception)   {
                                          tvData1.setText(exception.toString()+"  Or enter number is not Available!");                    
                            }

                    tvData1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                }
            });
```

## here is my logCat

05-10 10:27:43.507: I/Choreographer(2465): Skipped 119 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-10 10:49:24.247: D/(2539): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8570820, tid 2539
05-10 10:49:24.337: W/EGL_emulation(2539): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-10 10:49:24.337: D/OpenGLRenderer(2539): Enabling debug mode 0
05-10 11:15:44.547: D/dalvikvm(2539): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 172K, 8% free 3085K/3320K, paused 259ms, total 260ms
05-10 11:15:45.547: I/Choreographer(2539): Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-10 11:18:07.737: D/(2600): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb856bd40, tid 2600
05-10 11:18:07.887: W/EGL_emulation(2600): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-10 11:18:07.907: D/OpenGLRenderer(2600): Enabling debug mode 0
05-10 11:18:21.717: D/dalvikvm(2600): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 183K, 8% free 3073K/3320K, paused 78ms, total 96ms
05-10 11:18:22.197: W/System.err(2600): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG @2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@b3dea7b8) 
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2056)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at com.example.servicenew.YeniMainActivity$1.onClick(YeniMainActivity.java:77)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/System.err(2600):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 11:18:22.217: D/AndroidRuntime(2600): Shutting down VM
05-10 11:18:22.217: W/dalvikvm(2600): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ab5ba8)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600): Process: com.example.servicenew, PID: 2600
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:513)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at com.example.servicenew.YeniMainActivity$1.onClick(YeniMainActivity.java:84)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-10 11:18:22.277: E/AndroidRuntime(2600):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Post your logcat please..

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995928/org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparserexception-expected-start-tag-http-schemas-xmlso)

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430136/ksoap2-org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparserexception-expected-start-tag-error) too..

Comment: I looked before these links and I looked again.I took the same error when I did some modification.

Comment: where is the error in Logcat???

Comment: I wrote my logcat above

Comment: I used try-catch block and  error is written on textview.For this reason,Error wasn't display on logcat.

Comment: Remove that try catch and run..Then post the full logcat..