# Connect to a Delphi WebService with Android

Tags: android, web-services, delphi, soap, ksoap2

I wrote a simple webservice in Delphi XE
It is running on IIS, as ISAPI Dll.

I cant connect to this webservice with Android:

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://217.114.221.83/grigliamo/";
private final String URL = "http://217.114.221.83/grigliamo/DifferenziaWS.dll/wsdl/IWSDifferenzia";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://217.114.221.83/grigliamo/WS_Login";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "WS_Login";

public void getWebService(String x) {
    //Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        //Involve web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        Assign it to fahren static variable
        Res = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Res = e.toString();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I always get an org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expectd START_TAG
Can anybody tell me what's wrong on my webservice please?
Thanks
Andrea

Comment: `what's wrong on my webservice`. You are sure your webservice is wrong? Your Android code is ok?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430136/ksoap2-org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparserexception-expected-start-tag-error

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with the web service, SoapUI can retrieve the WSDL and send login requests.

I recommend to read [ksoap2 org.xmlpull.v1.xmlpullparserexception expected start_tag error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430136/ksoap2-org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparserexception-expected-start-tag-error)

The answers there contain step-by-step guides to build the correct SOAP request parameters / properties for a web service.