# {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <HTML>@2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@7232b24)

Tags: java, android, .net, ksoap2, webservice-client

I'm trying to connect to web service through android client (emulator) and I know there are quite a few similar questoins, but non of the solutions helped me so far. In particular, I followed first two answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430136/ksoap2-org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparserexception-expected-start-tag-error) question. I double-checked namespace, url, method name and soap_action strings several times, also, I tried assigning different values to `envelope.env` (not sure if it's a right way to do it though), but it did't really help. 
So what is next that I should do/change? I've been tackling this for two days now and it's getting a bit frustrating. Any help is appreciated

This error:

```
com.example.webserviceactivity W/System.err﹕ org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap}Envelope (position:START_TAG <HTML>@2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@b1272710)
```

This is my class

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private final String METHOD_NAME = "GetNextRow";
        private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetNextRow";
        private final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:63054/BundlesWS.asmx";
        private String TAG = "TAG";
        private static String newQuantity;
        private SoapObject resultRequestSOAP ;
        TextView tv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResultQTY);
}

public void btnQTY(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Quantity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
    task.execute();
}

public void getQuantity() {
    resultRequestSOAP = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    //Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

//Tried defferent values here:
//1. http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
//2. http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope
//3. http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/
//4. http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
//also I tried totally removing enelope.env..

    envelope.env = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap";
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(resultRequestSOAP);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        newQuantity = response.getProperty(0).toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        getQuantity();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        System.out.print(result);
        tv.setText(newQuantity + " units");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        tv.setText("Calculating...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my WSDL

```
     <wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
 xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <s:element name="GetNextRow">
    <s:complexType/>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="GetNextRowResponse">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetNextRowResult" type="tns:PickRow"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:complexType name="PickRow">
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemNo" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Quantity" type="s:int"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Location" ``type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Id" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    <s:element name="Report">
    <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="id" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="quantiy" type="s:int"/>
    </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
    <s:element name="ReportResponse">
    <s:complexType/>
    </s:element>
    </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="GetNextRowSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetNextRow"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetNextRowSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetNextRowResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ReportSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Report"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ReportSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ReportResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="BundlesWSSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetNextRow">
    <wsdl:input message="tns:GetNextRowSoapIn"/>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:GetNextRowSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Report">
    <wsdl:input message="tns:ReportSoapIn"/>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:ReportSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="BundlesWSSoap" type="tns:BundlesWSSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetNextRow">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetNextRow" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Report">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Report" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:binding name="BundlesWSSoap12" type="tns:BundlesWSSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetNextRow">
    <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetNextRow" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap12:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap12:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Report">
    <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Report" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap12:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap12:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="BundlesWS">
    <wsdl:port name="BundlesWSSoap" binding="tns:BundlesWSSoap">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost:63054/BundlesWS.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="BundlesWSSoap12" binding="tns:BundlesWSSoap12">
    <soap12:address location="http://localhost:63054/BundlesWS.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

Not sure if you need a full error log, if you do, I will gladly edit my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem, it seems this error occurs from issues related to problems most likely associated with these parameters: String

```
SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/hello";
   String  OPERATION_NAME="hello";
   String WSLD_NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org";
   String SOAP_ADDRESS="http://192.168.0.100:61585/Hello.asmx";
```

In my case it was simply because in the applicationHost.config file the binding of the site was restricted to only local host address:

```
   <bindings>
           <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61585:localhost" />
   </bindings>
```

changing to:

```
 <bindings>
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61585:*" />
```

solve my issue

Answer (score -1):

this is a very common issue, most of the times the reason is that one o more of this values are incorrect

```
private final String METHOD_NAME = "GetNextRow";
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetNextRow";
private final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:63054/BundlesWS.asmx";
```

Open the **WSDL** to get the correct values!.

http://10.0.2.2:63054/BundlesWS.asmx?wsdl

Comment: Thank you for response. But I have added a whole WSDL in the question. Is there anything else I'm supposed to add? Server is running on http://localhost:63054/BundlesWS.asmx , but 10.0.2.2 is for emulator